# zip and groupby curiosity in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Can someone explain why these output different things in Python 2.7.4?  They output the same thing in python 3.3.1.  I'm just wondering if this is a bug in 2.7 that was fixed in 3, or if it is due to some change in the language.

```
>>> for (i,j),k in zip(groupby([1,1,2,2,3,3]), [4,5,6]):
...     print list(j)
... 
[]
[]
[3]
>>> for i,j in groupby([1,1,2,2,3,3]):
...     print list(j)
... 
[1, 1]
[2, 2]
[3, 3]
```

Comment: Great question!  it had me stumped for a few minutes...

Answer (score 7):

This isn't a mistake.  It has to do with when the groupby iterable gets consumed.  Try the following with python3 and you'll see the same behavior:

```
from itertools import groupby
for (i,j),k in list(zip(groupby([1,1,2,2,3,3]), [4,5,6])):
    print (i,list(j),k)
```

Note that if you remove the outer `list`, then you get the result you expect.  The "problem" here is that the grouper object (returned in `j`) is an iterable which yields elements as long as they are the same.  It doesn't know ahead of time what it will yield or how many elements there are.  It just receives an iterable as input and then yields from that iterable.  If you move on to the next "group", then the iterable ends up being consumed before you ever get a chance to look at the elements.  This is a design decision to allow `groupby` to operate on iterables which yield arbitrary (even infinite) numbers of elements.

In python2.x, `zip` will create a list, effectively moving past each "group" before the loop even starts.  In doing so, it ends up consuming each of the "group" ojects returned by `groupby`.  This is why you only have the last element in the list reported.  The fix for python2.x is to use `itertools.izip` rather than `zip`.  In python3.x, `izip` became the builtin `zip`.  As I see it, the only way to support both in this script is via something like:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import groupby
try:
    from itertools import izip
except ImportError:  #python3.x
    izip = zip

for (i,j),k in izip(groupby([1,1,2,2,3,3]), [4,5,6]):
    print (i,list(j),k)
```

Comment: Better way would be to use the import syntax to make `zip` lazy - can't remember syntax ottomh

Comment: @JonClements -- I'm not sure I know what you're refering to, but I'm curious now.  I opened a Code Review question about it.  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26271/cleaner-way-to-import-izip-for-different-versions-of-python

Comment: To make `zip` lazy just `try: from itertools import izip as zip` etc. That makes more sense to me because then the rest of the code would work the same in 2.x and 3.x (wrt to this anyway).

Comment: @martineau -- Yeah, I've used that one too ... Basically it boils down to whether you want to look at things from a python2.x perspective or a python3.x perspective.

Comment: @JonClements -- I just saw this one again.  I think you might be refering to `from future_builtins import zip` which works starting with python2.6 IIRC